# Error in Swift 3 for calculate with String and Integer

Tags: ios, swift

This is a really simple program : Calculate Cat years

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtOldOfCat: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblOldOfCat: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgCat: UIImageView!


    @IBAction func btnSubmit(_ sender: Any) {

        print(txtOldOfCat.text!)

        let catAge = Int(txtOldOfCat.text!)! * 7

        print(catAge)

        lblOldOfCat.text = String(catAge)

    }
}
```

In the log console, if enter 3 to submit I can read that :

3
21
(11db)

The program breakpoint in Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1 in this line :

```
{ ...
    lblOldOfCat.text = String(catAge)
}
```

I double check and the link is good betweem my main storyboard and ViewController class.

I really not understand is really easy...

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a breakpoint set on that line (blue flag in the margin)?

Comment: .... YES !!! Thank you I don't know this function on XCode I'm new !

Comment: let catAge = Int(txtOldOfCat.text!)! * 7 would crash your app if the user enters a non digit character. you can use nil coalescing operator instead of forcing unwrap your number `let catAge = (Int(txtOldOfCat.text!) ?? 0) * 7`

Comment: Your question is unclear. The code you posted should display 2 integers, each on a separate line. You say you see "3 21 (11db)" in the console. That appears to show the input value (3) then the output on the same line, which is not what your code would output. And what is the "(11db)" part?

Comment: What results are you getting that are different from what you expect? Are you crashing, or not seeing the values you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your click on line number it's add a "blue flag' in the margin. This blue flag is a breakpoint in XCode so this is why my program stop at this line. You just need to re-click on the line in blue to delete this break point.